# How to handle very fast events in c#?

Tags: c#, events, com

I am writing a program (.net 4) that interacts with an external COM object. In the interest of having a "live" program, I am changing the program from polling the COM object and then doing calculations to receiving events from the COM object.

My issue is the events are too fast. As far as I can tell (in debug mode) some events are missed and so on.

The specific questions are:

1. How do I (or C#) make sure I catch and handle all the events?
2. How should the main be built to wait for an event (if there is a long time in between events) and not end?

I have tried a main with an infinite loop that sleeps for a millisecond and then spins off a thread, but that is just a big mess.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You need to show some code to make this answerable.

Comment: What do you mean by "events"? If the object exposes events, subscribe these events instead of polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I (or C#) make sure I catch and handle all the events?

BackgroundWorkers is great for problems like this: -

> How should the main be built to wait for an event (if there is a long
>   time in between events) and not end?

You should continously poll for events by using a `Timer`. You should simply handle the data as its received.

Without more information this question will be difficult to answer in more detail....

Comment: Why did I recieve a negative vote on this?